# How to convert ImageIcon to File object wihout saving it into disk?

Tags: java, swing, file, jdbc, imageicon

I want to send ImageIcon to database using jdbc.
I need to File object to do that.
How to convert ImageIcon to File wihout saving it into disk?

```
File fBlob = new File(imageIcon.getImage());
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream ( fBlob );
preparedStatement.setBinaryStream (3, is, (int) fBlob.length() );
```

Comment: No; you need a different kind of `InputStream`.

Comment: How did you create your ImageIcon in the first place? My guess is that you created it from an InputStream. So why not pass this InputStream to setBinaryStream()?

Comment: Blob blob = rset.getBlob(5); 
byte date[] = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());  
pictures.add(new ImageIcon(date));

Comment: save as `Blob` not as `File`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you could try to get a `byte array` from the `imageIcon` and then write it to the database. Something like this :

```
BufferedImage bi = getBufferedImage(imageIcon.getImage());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, formatType, baos);

byte[] byteArray= baos.toByteArray();

preparedStatement.setBytes(1, byteArray);
```

**EDIT :**

Use this method to convert the `Image` to a `BufferedImage` :

```
public static BufferedImage getBufferedImage(Image img)
{
    if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
    {
       return (BufferedImage) img;
    }

    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), 
                    img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    // Return the buffered image
    return bimage;
}
```

Comment: i got exception at cast:java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage